# Laravel: Data does not appear in view

Tags: php, laravel

my data does not appear in view
Below is my controller code I have difficulty in resolving this problem

```
public function prediksi()
        {
            $collection = array();
            $title = "Data Prediksi Sentimen";
            $testing_data = DataTesting::count();
            $klasifikasi = DataTesting::with(['data_crawling','klasifikasi'])->get();
            foreach($klasifikasi as $class){
                $prediksi = Klasifikasi::with(['sentimen'])->where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->first();
                $hasil = Hasil::where('id_testing',$class->id_testing)->get();
                $aktual = Sentimen::where('id_sentimen', $class->data_crawling->id_sentimen)->first();
                if($prediksi && isset($prediksi->kategori)){
                      $collection[] = [
                    'id_testing' => $class->id_testing,
                    'username' => $class->data_crawling->username,
                    'tweet' => $class->data_crawling->tweet,
                    'kategori' => $aktual->kategori,
                    'prediksi' => $prediksi->sentimen->kategori,
                ];
                 $hasil_data[$class->id_testing][] = $hasil;
                }
            }

            return view('visualisasi.prediksi', compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil_data']));
        }
```

And below is my code view

```
<?php $no=1; ?>
@foreach($collection as $key)
<tr>
    @foreach($hasil_data[$key['id_testing']] as $hasil){
    dd($hasil);
    <td align="center">{{$no++ ."."}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{$key['username']}}</td>
    <td align="left"><a data-toggle="modal"
            href="#Detail_{{$key['id_testing']}}"> {{$key['tweet']}}</a></td>
    <td align="center">{{$key['kategori']}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{$key['prediksi']}}</td>
}
    @endforeach

</tr>
@endforeach
```

Is there something wrong in my controller or in my view? please help me in finding a solution

Comment: Do you get any error or warning ?

Comment: idk, what are you expecting? what is actually happening? etc etc

Comment: @RishiRaut I did not get an error message

Comment: Please read about [laravel realtion] (https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @lagbox I want my data to appear on my view blade

Comment: what data do you want to appear? what line isn't working? some context

Comment: @lagbox data from $ predictions, actual $, $ results, I don't understand which line isn't working, because all the data isn't appearing, I think the error might be in my controller or my view

Comment: try send just variable with compact and dd test in view and tell me about that plz

Comment: @hashemsheikhypour I tried dd (compact (['title', 'collection', 'testing_data', 'result_data'])); and display the following data array: 3 [▼
  "title" => "Sentiment Prediction Data"
  "collection" => []
  "testing_data" => 100
]
but the data in $ collection does not appear, and in my view it does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-dd) on your view (line #5) which ends the execution of the script. Remove it and place it before `return` on your controller to dump the given vars and check your data before passing them to your view:

```php
dd(compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil_data']));

return view('visualisasi.prediksi', compact(['title','collection','testing_data','hasil_data']));
```

If the dumped vars were looking fine, you can remove `dd()` and debug your view.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204657/discussion-on-answer-by-hafez-divandari-laravel-data-does-not-appear-in-view).